# Embedding YouTube on CartoDB infowindows

Tags: carto, infowindow, embeddable-web-maps, youtube

I am embedding my CartoDb as follows

```
$('#map').ready(function(e){
    cartodb.createVis('map', '//internetadventureclub.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/617ba774-fd8c-11e4-9e57-0e4fddd5de28/viz.json', {https: true});
  });
```

How can i enable `sanitizeTemplate:false` in the above so that the YouTube Video can be played in the infowindow of CartoDB

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an example of sanitization by using createViz:

```
 cartodb.createVis('map', 'viz.json', { description: true, search: true, shareable: true })
      .on('done', function(vis,layers) {

        var layer = layers[1].getSubLayer(0);
        //layer.infowindow.set('template', $('#infowindow_template').html());
        layer.infowindow.set('sanitizeTemplate', 'false');

        layer.on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('error: ' + err);
        });

      }).on('error', function() {
        console.log("some error occurred");
      });
```

Comment: this cant be done from inside the the cartoDB app?

Comment: Nope. Inside the CartoDB Editor you cannot generate your own scripts neither embed external sites as this is quite insecure for the users of the platform and the viewers of the maps.